# Having trouble setting up inventory

Tags: python, inventory, adventure

I'm working on a text-based game where the player had to find 6 items in different rooms before running into the boss or they die. I have the items set in the dict with the rooms but I don't know how to pull from it as the player moves around. What I have currently have has the player able to add things to the inventory but then it's stuck in a permanent loop. I am very new at this and I am having trouble connecting things together. Here is the whole thing with comments.

```
rooms = {

    'Entry Way': { 'North': 'Stalagmite Cavern'},
    'Stalagmite Cavern': {'North': 'Grand Cavern', 'South': 'Entry Way', 'item': 'torch'},
    'Grand Cavern': {'North': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Armory', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Stalagmite Cavern', 'item': 'cross'},
    'Armory': {'North': 'Treasure Trove', 'West': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'Stake'},
    'Treasure Trove': {'South': 'Armory', 'item': 'silver'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Storage', 'East': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'elaborate comb'},
    'Storage': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'mirror'},
    'Hallway': {'North': 'Cliff Top', 'South': 'Grand Cavern'},
    'Cliff Top': {'South': 'Hallway', 'item': 'Orla'}
}

def show_instructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print("Thousand Year Vampire")
   print("Collect 6 items to defeat the vampire or be destroyed by her.")
   print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
   print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")

def show_status():
    print(current_room)
    print(inventory)
    #print the player's current location
    #print the current inventory
    #print an item if there is one

# setting up inventory
inventory = []

def game():
    inventory = []
    # simulate picking up items
    while True:
        item = input()
        if item in inventory:  # use in operator to check membership
            print("you already have got this")
            print(" ".join(inventory))
        else:
            print("You got ", item)
            print("its been added to inventory")
            inventory.append(item)
            print(" ".join(inventory))

# setting the starting room
starting_room = 'Entry Way'

# set current room to starting room
current_room = starting_room

#show game instructions
show_instructions()

show_status()


while True:
    print("\nYou are currently in the {}".format(current_room))
    move = input("\n>> ").split()[-1].capitalize()
    print('-----------------------------')

    # user to exit
    if move == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
        break

    # a correct move
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
        print('inventory:', inventory)


    # incorrect move
    else:
        print("You can't go that way. There is nothing to the {}".format(move))

#loop forever until meet boss or gets all items and wins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice start from you, Here is some modification as a small push to inspire your thoughts, and you can complete yourself or change according to the scenario you prefer- but discover the changes your self :) I have tested this code:

```
rooms = {

    'Entry Way': { 'North': 'Stalagmite Cavern'},
    'Stalagmite Cavern': {'North': 'Grand Cavern', 'South': 'Entry Way', 'item': 'torch'},
    'Grand Cavern': {'North': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Armory', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Stalagmite Cavern', 'item': 'cross'},
    'Armory': {'North': 'Treasure Trove', 'West': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'Stake'},
    'Treasure Trove': {'South': 'Armory', 'item': 'silver'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Storage', 'East': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'elaborate comb'},
    'Storage': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'mirror'},
    'Hallway': {'North': 'Cliff Top', 'South': 'Grand Cavern'},
    'Cliff Top': {'South': 'Hallway', 'item': 'Orla'}
}

def show_instructions():
   #print the main menu and the commands
   print("Thousand-Year Vampire")
   print("Collect 6 items to defeat the vampire or be destroyed by her.")
   print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
   print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")

def show_status():
    print(current_room)
    print(inventory)
    #print the player's current location
    #print the current inventory
    #print an item if there is one

# setting up inventory
inventory = []

def game(item):
    # simulate picking up items
    if item in inventory:  # use in operator to check membership
        print("you already have got this")
        print(" ".join(inventory))
    else:
        print("You got ", item)
        print("its been added to inventory")
        inventory.append(item)
        print(" ".join(inventory))

# setting the starting room
starting_room = 'Entry Way'

# set current room to starting room
current_room = starting_room

#show game instructions
show_instructions()

show_status()


while True:
    print("\nYou are currently in the {}".format(current_room))
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        game(rooms[current_room]['item'])

    move = input("\n>> ").split()[-1].capitalize()
    print('-----------------------------')

    # user to exit
    if move == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
        break

    # a correct move
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]
        #print('inventory:', inventory)

    # incorrect move
    else:
        print("You can't go that way. There is nothing to the {}".format(move))

#loop forever until meeting boss or gets all items and wins
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If each room only has one item, I think that the following line in the game() function should be removed

```
while True:
```

since that will cause an infinite loop with the first three printouts being "You got..." and "... added to inventory ..." and "[contents of inventory]" but the next printouts will be "you have already got this" and "[contents of inventory]" over and over again.

Comment: That does help but only 6 of the 8 rooms have items. How can I show that the 6 rooms have the items in it?

Comment: Where is the game() function called in the code you provided? I think that will help me answer your question

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure where to put it. When I put it under the call function `show_status` it just starts an endless loop where the user can add items to the inventory but I only want the player to be able to select certain items in certain rooms. the items are listed at the end of each room dict at the top.

Comment: Perhaps put it after the line current_room = rooms[current_room][move], and remove the while True in the game() function. Also, you will need to create something like a dictionary with the keys being the locations and the values being the items at those locations (and perhaps use something like None for the values of the locations without items) so you can fully represent the state of the world. Remember to change the corresponding value of a location to None when you pick up the item at that location.

Comment: Okay! That helped me a lot! I can now move rooms and add items but they can add any item they want. How can I make it so they can only take from the items in the dict?

Comment: Are you randomizing the items that you put in the rooms? In any case, just check if the item they want is in the value set (aka dict.values()). Also, check if it is not none.